# could not local host after ng build with base href asssign

Tags: javascript, angular, nginx

i have done ng build --base-href /emp/ after that i have link the dist folder to var/www/html and then i have configured my nginx default server , but7 when i localhost/emp/ its showing this error..

```
runtime.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
polyfills.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
styles.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
vendor.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
main.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

Comment: Are those console errors in the browser? What's in the runtime.js when viewed in the browser? I would presume the request for runtime.js and alike is returning an error page from nginx and the unexpected `<` is the beginning of some HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Method 1 :

Mention the base href="/yourprojectfolderpath/dist/" in index.html file

then run the following command

ng build --prod.

Open the browser & run the your project via

localhost/yourprojectfolderpath/dist/

**OR**

Method 2 :

just set the base path via command line

ng build --prod --base-href="/yourprojectfolderpath/dist/"

Open the browser & run the your project via

localhost/yourprojectfolderpath/dist/

I hope this will be useful.

Comment: Angular 7 (i think 6 and above) should set the base path either from the command line or in the workspace settings of the `angular.json` file. You should not edit the html directly.

Comment: Yes you can also set the base href via command line like ng build --prod --base-href="/yourprojectfolderpath/dist/" so then no need to edit the index.html file.